# How deleted answers affect the post ban?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, post-ban

I have a friend who likes to post answers on Stack Overflow. Sometimes he gets overexcited in the rush to post first, and he posts nonsense. When he cools down and looks over his answer he realizes his error and feels a little embarrassed and ashamed. So he deletes his post.

He's concerned that his account might end up being post banned from posting new answers. (as a result of these deleted posts)

What proportion of posts can be deleted before an account runs the risk of being post banned? (my friend is deleting less than 10% of his post)

UPDATE

This isn't a duplicate. The referenced question was asking about deleted questions. I'm asking about deleted answers

Comment: Stop posting nonsense...

Comment: sorry, you mean tell my friend to stop posting nonsense.

Comment: Are you asking about the automatic answer ban or a moderator triggered suspension?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: The automatic ban (my friends useful, and well thought out answers would probably deter a moderator from initiating a suspension)

Comment: Then you won't get an answer, the details of the automatic bans are intentionally kept secret. Security through obscurity...

Comment: There is huge difference between post ban and suspension..

Comment: To answer the question: the post ban algorithm is a secret on purpose; we can't know the exact effect of deleted posts but being here enough time I can tell it has a big impact. Better leave a downvoted answer around than deleting it. (assuming of course it can't be edited to correct form)

Comment: Perhaps your friend can have you post answers for him as well if he's not entirely sure. Then he won't risk a ban.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The question referenced is about deleted questions. I'm asking about deleted answers (and since the algorithm is a secret there's no way to know that it's the same thing)

Comment: @AidanEwen The answers won't be any different for answers than for questions.

Answer (score 9):

If your friend is posting 'nonsense', and then realizing it's so bad that he has to delete it, then yes; he *is* potentially risking being answer banned, or otherwise suspended.

If your friend has this problem, he needs to do this: Don't hit "POST" until he is sure he means to post what he has written.

Also recommended: Outdoor activities, such as frolicking with unicorns.

Comment: My friend is allergic to horses (and cats) - it's very likely that unicorns would make him sneeze. And I will certainly advise him to be more careful.

Comment: Outdoor activities? You mean [The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/), right?

Comment: @AidanEwen Unicorns are hypoallergenic.

Comment: Unicorn here. I can confirm that we're much safer than our terrestrial cousins.

Comment: What's wrong with our terrestrial unicorns, eh? You alien unicorns come over here, steal our unicorns' jobs...